# ST2's Less2css throws problems in console

Tags: sublimetext2

I try to get on with Sublime text 2. Since I'm a LESS user, I wanted to have a watcher/compiler. I installed Less2css and configured it. When I try to compile my LESS file, console throws me this:

```
[less2css] Converting (...)style.less to (...)style.css
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\sublime_plugin.py", line 362, in run_
    return self.run(edit)
  File ".\less2css.py", line 38, in run
  File ".\lesscompiler.py", line 83, in convertOne
  File ".\lesscompiler.py", line 204, in convertLess2Css
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xbf in position 32: ordinal not in range(128)
```

And the file isn't compiled. How can I fix this?

This problem occures even with empty or very simple file.

Comment: Do you have any class names or `content` rules involving diacritical letters? That could lead to problems like the one you describe.

Comment: No, nothing like that.